# SQL String Pattern Matching

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a simple select query on a table to exclude all the records containing a single word on Snowflake.

For E.g. there is a column - " NAME" having datatype - STRING - containing a single word and combination of words.

I want to build a query to exclude all iterations of a sub-string present in that column ( uppercase,lowercase and camel-case via a single query)

Comment: You may need Regex to match string with your filter rules

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.  Examples of what should be filtered out and not filtered out, for instance.  For instance, "contain a single word" and "sub-string" are not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am trying to run a simple select query on a table to exclude all the records containing a single word*

You could use `ILIKE` to perform case-insensitive comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE NAME NOT ILIKE '%phrase%';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a20287ea2faae6bbae2c4caad7fe48a9)**

Comment: Thanks mate , used your suggestion and it worked.

Comment: @AadeshShukla Great to hear it :) [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)